# What is the difference between "dynamic import" and regular import in react?

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between "dynamic import" (using React.lazy) and regular import in react?

Dynamic import:

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
```

**vs.**

Regular import:

```
import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent';
```

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/lazy-loading-components-in-react-16-6-6cea535c0b52/

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy

Comment: as @DigitalJedi mentioned, it's not dynamic, it's lazy loaded, by making a http request for a module (or a part of your application aka component) when required, whereas in regular import, that one is made at compile time, so your app bundle will contain all the features at runtime

Answer (score 0):

On **Dynamic import**, you import the component on reaching the expression:

```js
let OtherComponent = undefined;
// Never imported.
if (false) {
  OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent.jsx'));
}
```

On **Regular import**, you import the component on component call:

```js
// AB.jsx
import AB from './AB.jsx';

function App() {
  // imports A and B
  return <AB/>
}
```

```js
// AB.jsx
import A from './A.jsx';
import B from './B.jsx';

// B is imported altought never used.
function AB() {
  return <A/>; 
}
```